# How to calculate Native Heap memory size in java process for Hotspot JVM

Tags: java, jvm, metaspace

According to my understanding , Native Heap is the memory left after allocating the maximum Heap size for a java process.
For a 32 bit Java process - the maximum Virtual memory that can be allocated to this process will be 4GB. out of this total 4GB , suppose we have set 2GB for max Heap and 1GB is used by OS. Then, the remaining 1GB memory can be called as Native Heap?

Similarly , for 64 bit java process, the max memory that can be allocated to process can be greater than 4GB.  Lets say, i have 16GB RAM in my system, then maximum Virtual memory that can be allocated to each process in my system will be 16GB as the **Virtual Address Space range** will not allow more than 16GB of memory.is it right?

So, Native Heap for 64 bit java process will (16- 2(-Xmx) -1(OS)) i.e 15GB?

Is my understanding about Native Heap calculation is correct?

If my understanding is correct, then why we say that max available memory for **Metaspace** which is allocated from Native memory is **total available system memory**. The maximum virtual memory that each process get will be maximum virtual addressable range possible in system and out of this some amount of memory will be occupied by heap and OS.

If we set the total memory allocated to process as heap memory, then will it Not throw **outOfMemoryError:Metaspace** as there will no Native Heap available for this process?

Please help me to correct my understanding . Thanks.

Comment: *Is my understanding about Native Heap calculation is correct?* - No. First of all, what do you mean "Native Heap"? Virtual address space is limited by 256 TB (2⁴⁸), no matter how much RAM you have.

Comment: Native Heap here i mean the memory left after setting the max Heap size(-Xmx) for java process.Why are taking the power of 48? If 256 TB is total virtual address space, then how much virtual memory is allocated to each process running in system by OS?

Comment: Virtual memory management is a very broad topic - I'm afraid it's not possible to explain it in a single Stack Overflow answer. If you have a specific problem (e.g. OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace), please narrow down the question to this particular problem.

Comment: Can you please explain me max virtual memory that can be allocated to a 64 bit process  in system having 16GB  or 8 GB of RAM . As i understand, for a 64 bit process , max addressable range is 2^64 i.e 16 exabytes. But if my system has only 16 GB of memory , it will be limited to only 2^16. How it can be more than this range. Even if it uses disk memory for storing data , ultimately  the addresses that the CPU would use should be of main memory only. The virtual addresses will mapped from main memory addresss. So, How Virtual memory allocated for each process is independent of RAM installed?

Comment: Virtual memory is not simply *allocated* - it can be *reserved*, *committed* and even *overcommitted*. The virtual pages can be backed by physical memory, by a file, by swap or by nothing at all. They can be compressed or uncompressed; shared or unshared; evictable or unevictable etc. So the question about "max virtual memory" is not quite correct... Or I can simply answer that this depends on the particular OS and the particular architecture.

Comment: There’s no sense in making up your own term, like “Native Heap”, define it as you like and expect *us* to answer questions about it. It will behave as you like, as it is your invention. A maximum size does not report what is guaranteed to be available, it just tells you that the JVM will not use more than that.